# Generators of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$?

Tags: group-theory

It's stated in Serre's book "Trees" that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$ is the amalgamated product of two copies of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ along the subgroup $\Gamma_0(p)$. Unfortunately, it doesn't give the isomorphism.

My question is - what is this isomorphism? In particular, what is a minimal set of generators for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[1/p])$?

Answer (score 4):

According to Section 4 of Behr-Mennicke's ["A Presentation of the Groups $PSL(2,p)$"](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v20/cjm1968v20.1432-1438.pdf), a set of generators are:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\qquad B = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\qquad U = \begin{bmatrix}p & 0 \\0 & p^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

They even give a full set of relations:

$$B^2 = (AB)^3,\qquad B^4=1,\qquad U^{-1}AU = A^{p^2},\qquad (UB)^2 = B^2$$
where the first two are relations for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

When $p = 2$ there is an additional relation:
$$(UA^2B)^3 = B^2$$

Comment: A stable link for the paper: https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1968-144-7

Answer (score 1):

In my recent paper ([arXiv:2401.08146](https://arxiv.org/abs/2401.08146)) on the abelianization of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{m}])$, I show that the two matrices
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \quad Q_m = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1/m \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
generate $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{m}])$ for all $m \geq 1$ (not just prime $m$).

For $m=2$, one also finds the presentation
$$
\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]) \cong \langle x, y \mid x^2yx^2 = yx^2y, \: y^2xy^2 = xy^2x, \: (xy^2x)^4 = 1\rangle.
$$
The isomorphism is given by $A \mapsto x$ and $Q_2 \mapsto y$ (or vice versa; the presentation is symmetric).